# How to display flex css actually work (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

i wanna ask something about display flex

```
<div class="container mx-auto">
       <div class="d-flex">
           <div class="bg-red-300  w-100 mr-3">halo</div>
           <div class="bg-red-300  w-50 mr-3">halo</div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

how to display flex can manage width flex item with width 100% and 50% ?
[image]

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

In BS, if you want to have that kind of 2:1 ratio of width of elements, you'd have to use the grid system. Your above code will turn into:

```
<div class="container mx-auto">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 bg-red-300 mr-3">halo</div>
            <div class="col-4 bg-red-300 mr-3">halo</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what i wana ask what if we have used display flex? why output like that *picture*?

Comment: `row` does use display flex. You can inspect it in the browser and check.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use Flex's Bootstrap,
The 'col' has to be used to give the width of the box

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 bg-red-300">halo</div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-red-300">halo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```